# Windows 10 -> Raspberry PI 4 Samba Share Speed extremely slow unless pause and resume

Tags: performance, samba

I've been trying to set up my Raspberry PI 4 as a home media server and was planning to use Samba to transfer files from my Windows 10 PC to the Raspberry PI. Currently, I get speeds of <5 MB/s unless, for some reason, if I pause the transfer and then resume the transfer I get a spike of 100 MB/s for a couple seconds and then speeds drop back down to <5 MB/s like so:
[image]

I've tried:

- Booting from an external SSD
- Booting from an M.2 NVME SSD
- Booting from my SD Card and using the M.2 NVME SSD as external storage
- Just Booting from an SD Card
- Connecting a CAT 6 Ethernet cable to my PC and a CAT 6 Ethernet cable to my Raspberry PI does bring it up to 15 MB/s but the same pause/unpause behavior happens

The problem remains. Any ideas of what could be the problem/what could be done or any information I could provide would be appreciated.

Comment: Symptoms may be of rpi or windows disk rate.  How is the media server disk set up? Are you reading or writing to the server?

Comment: Currently writing to the server...though it seems the low speeds go both ways. The media server disk is an NVME M.2 SSD currently in an encasing connected to the RPi with a USB c -> USB A cable in the USB 3.1 slot with Raspbian, Jellyfin, and a pi-hole set up on it if that's what you mean.

Comment: Behavior is indicative of bottleneck with faster cache.  Pausing gives an opportunity to use up cache which becomes available for a burst of speed up on resume, until it fills up again.

Comment: what brand/model is this M.2 card

Comment: SSD Card is an Inland Prime 1 TB NVME PCIE Gen 3x4.

as for the caching issue...that's also what I was thinking, but the issue seemed consistent across the above NVME I'm using, the SD card I tried, and the External T7 Samsung SSD I tried to use...otherwise if it was a CPU level caching issue wouldn't it be an issue on all RPi4s?

Comment: Have also been noticing something...the transfer rate dips to 5 MB/s sometimes, but unplugging the ethernet cable and plugging it back in brings it back to 15 MB/s for some reason? Not sure if that's helpful